# Passing Activity context to android Library - Is this the right approach?

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks

I am creating a android library, that need to get the layout informations from Activities in background. So this is what I have done :

1) called the library in onPause() for an Activity:

```
Mylibrary.start(this)
```

2) Inside the library, i am passing this context to create a static object of a different class. like

```
private static DiffClass myClass;
..........
public void start(Activity activity)
{
    myClass = new DiffClass(activity);
}
```

3) Next in onPause() of the activity, I am calling sdk to mark  this object as null to avoid memory leak problem . like :

```
MyLibrary.stop()    //inside onPause() of the Activity
```

and inside the sdk :

```
public void stop(){
       myClass =null;    //making the object holding activity reference null
    }
```

Is this the best approach ? Because I don't want the application context and also I need the activity context for a static class outside activity?